# How do I stop excel from automatically adding an "@" to the beginning of my formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a project in which I need to use VBA to create a formula that links cells together. The line of code I am using to do this is:

```
wb1.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Formula = "=[File Name]Sheet1!D100:D120
```

When I use that line of code, I get a value error and the formula bar of cell A1 looks like this:

```
"=@[File Name]Sheet1!D2900:2902"
```

Removing the "@" gets rid of the error and the formula works fine.

I would love some help in making it so that excel doesn't automatically insert the @ sign when I run the code. Thanks!

Comment: Use `.Formula2` instead of `.Formula`.